# Django: Cropping not working with django-image-cropping

Tags: python, django, image, forms, crop

I am trying to use django-image-cropping so that people on a blog can upload a profile picture to comment. However I am running into issues because the documentation is confusing me. In my custom user model, I have:

```
image = ImageCropField(blank=True,upload_to='uploaded_images')
cropping = ImageRatioField('image','430x360',size_warning=True)
```

Then in forms.py i do this:

```
class ExtraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegisterUser
        fields = ['image','cropping']
```

Finally in views I pass in the form as context:

```
imageForm = ExtraForm(request.POST or None)
context={
"extraForm":imageForm
}
```

However when I do {{ extraForm }} in my template it does not work, even if i do {{ extraForm.media }} in the head, and i do {% load cropping %} at the top. i can upload a picture but no cropping option pops up when I do. I know I am doing something wrong, but I'm not exactly sure what. Help me please...Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full "view" method?

Comment: @Tony that is it plus  return render(request,"viewProfile.html",context)